# Bash script - Select command and cut results

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting, cut

I'm working on a file that contains info such as:
service.txt

```
service1 - info1
service2 - info2
service3 - info3
...
```

I added each line of the file to an array. Subsequently with the select command I want to query the elements of the array displaying only the "serviceN" and display the "info" once the element has been selected.
At the moment I can't cut the line to display only the "service"
`

```
#File example
#service.txt
#service1 - info1
#service2 - info2
#...
#serviceN - infoN

#!/bin/bash
file='service.txt'
line=()
while read -r line; do
        line+=($line)
done < $file

echo "Select the service..."
select line in ${line[@]}; do      # how can i use "cut" here?
        echo $line
        break
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Seems a lot of work to do in bash. It feels like something that could be done in a 1 liner `grep`, `perl` or `awk` instead of all that line, looping logic you got there. e.g. `grep service service.txt`?

Comment: I historicized each line into an array to have the ability to select it.
Now i removed the loop while and add this:
mapfile line < $file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `cut` for this particular problem. In pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t lines < service.txt
echo "Select the service..." >&2
select service in "${lines[@]%%[[:blank:]]*}"; do
    echo "$service"
    break
done
```

For the `"${lines[@]%%[[:blank:]]*}"`, see [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), paragraph starting with **${parameter%word}**.

Comment: this method is very effective, but when I select the service it sends me the "truncated" line in output without displaying the info. It memorize the result of ${lines[@]%%[[:blank:]]*} and use that

Comment: @Seawolf02 `echo "${lines[REPLY]}"` if you want the whole line after `select`.

Comment: @Seawolf02 Or, `echo "${lines[REPLY]#*- }"` if you want just the info portion (the substring following the first `- ` )

Comment: Yeah it works, but if i select the 1) (service1) it prints in output the next line (service2)

Comment: @Seawolf02 Oops, my fault. Replace the `REPLY` with `REPLY-1` in my comments.